# HTML Encoding in OBIEE 12C

Tags: html, encoding, obiee

I'm new to OBIEE since a few weeks and got stumbled upon a problem: I created an action link "Navigate to a web page" to another page of my dashboard. I used this because I want to pass arguments from different prompts and columns (which I think is not possible via Navigate to BI content). When I define the parameters I have linked all the values to the appropriate columns. In one column I look up the full name of a persion in this format: "Surname Name". What OBIEE does when showing the results is creating two different values: "Surname" and "Name" divided by a semicolon which results in my analysis not working (obviously).

I looked in the url and right now it passes the argument as following &val5=%22Surname%22+%22Name%22 and I know it should be &val5=Surname%20Name.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: use JS: "Surname Name".replace(/\s/g,'%20');

Comment: I'm pretty sure OBIEE will pass variables (presentation variables and prompted content) to another analysis if you use the "Navigate to BI content" option. As long as that other analysis has filters set up correctly to listen to prompted content/presentation variables are defined correctly.

Comment: Mark P., you're right, I made it work with this option yesterday so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Navigate to BI content" --> This passes all prompted content and presentation variables. Then put up the right filters so no need for the HTML encoding.